# How would I center my h2 elements with my p elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

My issues is how the h2 elements(Introduction and Skills) are not centered. It would also help if you could help me center my `<p>` elements too. Another thing is how I don't understand why even though the `<p>` elements look aligned the same amount, they are aligned right a different amount (p#first and p#second).

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/kgaudel7/pen/NvRQqB)

```css
header {
  background: #062554;
  color: white;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.1em;
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  border: white solid 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 40px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 90px;
}

ul {
  font-size: 25px;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
}

nav a,
nav a:visited {
  color: #fff;
}

nav a.selected,
nav a:hover {
  color: #f4f4f4;
}

p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Verdana;
  background: #062554;
  color: white;
  border: black hidden 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-width: 10px;
}

p#first {
  width: 690px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.heading-main {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.headertekst {
  text-align: center;
}

p#second {
  width: 690px;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#bio-text {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<header>
  <div class="main-header">
    <h1><span>PlayOnPlayuh</span></h1>
    <h3>Website Developer and Entrepeneur</h3>
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#bio">Introduction</a></li>
      <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main-section bio row" id="bio">
    <div id="bio-text">
      <h2 class="headertekst">Introduction</h2>
      <p id="first"> HEllo</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-section" id="skills">
    <h2 class="headertekst">Skills</h2>
    <p id="second">My main tools for web development are HTML and CSS (Intermediate level), Javascript (Intermediate), BootStrap 4(Novice) along with Notepad and Brackets as code editors.</p>

</html>
```

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Answer (score 0):

you can use css:

```
h1, p {text-align:center;}
```

or put your h1 and p tags inside center tag `<center><p></p></center>`  `<center><h1></h1></center>`

Comment: `<center>` is deprecated in HTML5: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `text-align: center` is that it works inside the boundaries of the element itself.
In your example, the elements were not centered in the page in the first place, so `text-align: center` did not work. I would highly recommend using Chrome Dev Tools in order to understand how the elements are laid-out in the page.

In any case, in order to solve your problem I used `margin: 0 auto` in order to center **elements** in the page.
Also, I noticed that you used `left`/`right` and relative positioning in order to center elements, which I wouldn't advise doing...

See the final solution here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PKbvLY.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.headertekst {
width:650px;
position: relative;
text-align:center;
right:-691px;
}
```

The position of paragraph is in the right and heading width 100% in the center so heading is not in the paragraph alignment center